# Django - changing value from db in place and save it to db

Tags: python, html, django

I have  table on my page like that:

[image: table]

And models.py like that:

**models.py**

```
class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    author = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    category = models.IntegerField()
    offset_pages = models.IntegerField()
    read_pages = models.IntegerField()
    total_pages = models.IntegerField()
    book_path = models.CharField(max_length=200, default='')
    status = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.category} | {self.title} | {self.author}'
```

I would like to click on value in "Read pages" column (404 in this case) and then modify it and save to database.

The only way I see it for now is to make an html input there with assigned value of 404, then change it within an input and submit it with additional button.

I know how to do so, but it seems to me like there has to be way better solution.
Does any onemay present me another solution?

Comment: Add a bootstrap modal on the click event of the value, in this case 404. Create a form with post method inside that modal and save the data.

Comment: Thanks, I haven't use them earlier, but it looks like great solution for me.

Comment: @AagamSheth Do you know how send this value (404) to the modal?

Answer (score 1):

You can use JavaScript for that. You can define an `onclick` attribute for the read pages values and when the user clicks it, you can replace the text with an input field whose `value` attribute should be dynamically set to the value of the text.
The input field can have a small "ok" button next to it, which when pressed have to use an ajax call to update the the database and changing the displayed value without reloading the page.